# How to add meta tags in Wordpress for each post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have multiple  single-episodes.php single-movies.php single-seasons.php single-tvshows.php and I want each of them to have custom meta tags title  and description I'm not good in coding so i was looking for a solution in google and i found this

> To set the description to be unique on each posts you can add a conditional tag query that asks “If this is a single post view, show the post description of your choice; if this is a multi-post view, show the blog name and description.” The conditional tag query looks like this:

```
<meta name="description" content="<?php if ( is_single() ) { single_post_title('', true); } else { echo "description of your choice"; } ?>" />
```

how  i can implament this code in the header so each single take a custome meta tags

Comment: Please don't SHOUT when posting your question title.

Comment: not understand what u want to say please explain

Comment: Exactly what I said. Do not SHOUT (type your title in ALL CAPS) when posting here. Like everywhere else on the internet, SHOUTING is considered rude. You don't need to SHOUT to get your question noticed here. We answer thousands of questions a day asked by users who do not SHOUT AT US.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with the function `is_single()` in your `<head>` section.

Source : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/
Here is a working demo : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/#comment-496

`is_single('my-slug');
// When the Post with post_name (slug) of "my-slug" is being displayed.`

For the purpose of the post, I coded it for you below.

```
<?php 

// Variables
$my_custom_title = '';
$my_custom_description = '';

if(is_single('episodes')) {
   $my_custom_title = 'Episodes';
   $my_custom_description = 'My custom description for episodes.';
}
elseif(is_single('seasons')) {
   $my_custom_title = 'Seasons';
   $my_custom_description = 'My custom description for seasons.';
}
elseif(is_single('tvshows')) {
   $my_custom_title = 'TV Shows';
   $my_custom_description = 'My custom description for TV shows.';
}
else {
   $my_custom_title = get_bloginfo('name');
   $my_custom_description = get_bloginfo('description');
}
?>

<title><?php echo $my_custom_title; ?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $my_custom_description; ?>" />
```

To know more about `get_bloginfo()` : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_bloginfo/

Comment: thks for the response I implemented the code in the header but i got error "syntax error unexpected ';' " in the line    $my_custom_title = 'Episodes'; another question just implementing the code in the header will override the default meta tags for each single

Comment: I probably did a small typo error. To your question about overriding the default meta tags, you can just place it in the `else`

Comment: @MouhcinIuoanid You could try again. I had errors in the code. It was missing some `)`